# Need help finding where this error is coming from

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

this is my first post on StackOverflow.
I am currently writing a program in which I create three programs; Client, Pet and a Driver. The driver reads the data from a text file (clientdata.txt).

The Client requires an array of Pets as a field, and the list of Clients and Pets have differing arrangements in the text file so it is needed to be separated.

The code I am having problems with is when I separate the data into a array of five Clients and into an array of Pets. I am getting a NullPointerException when I try
 client[count].pet[0] = new Pet(input2[0], input2[1], input2[2], input2[3], input2[4]);  while inside the first for loop.
Where is the NullPointerException coming from and how do I fix it?

I am required to use the BlueJ Java program.

This is the Driver java file, error is occurring in the first for loop where the above line of code is.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    /**
      * Write a description of class Driver here.
      * 
      * @author 
      * @version 11-20-15
      */
      public class Driver
      {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
        Pet[] pet;
        //Client[] client;
        Client[] client = new Client[5];
        String[] input = new String[16];
        String holder;
        String line;
        String line2;
        String line3;
        int line4;
        int line5;
        double line6;
        String fileName;
        Scanner keyboard;
        Scanner dataFile;
        //StringTokenizer token;
        int size1;
        int size2;
        int m = 0;
        int n = 0;
        int count = 0;


   keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   //System.out.println("Enter in the size of the pet array: ");
   //size1 = keyboard.nextInt();
  // pet = new Pet[size1];  //must be 16 to work with the given clientdata.txt file
  // System.out.println("Enter in the size of the client array: ");
   //size2 = keyboard.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Please enter in the name of the data file. ");
   fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
   dataFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
  // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileName);
   while(dataFile.hasNextLine())
   {
       input[m] = dataFile.nextLine();
       m++;
    }
    m = 0;
   ///where to sort data
   while(m < 16)
   {
       String[] data = input[m].split(",");
       client[count] = new Client(data[0],data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6]);
       if(client[n].numberOfPets == 1)
       {
         m++;
         String [] input2 = input[m].split(",");
         client[count].pet[0] = new Pet(input2[0], input2[1], input2[2], input2[3], input2[4]);

       }
       else if(client[n].numberOfPets > 1)
       {
           for(int p = 0; p < client[n].numberOfPets; p++)
           {
             m++;
             String [] input2 = input[m].split(",");
             client[count].pet[0] = new Pet(input2[0], input2[1], input2[2], input2[3], input2[4]);  
             //pet = new Pet(input2[0], input2[1], input2[2], input2[3], input2[4]);
            }
       }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < client[n].numberOfPets; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(client[n].toString());
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < client[n].numberOfPets; i2++)
        {
            System.out.println(client[n].pet[n].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Client java file

```
        public class Client
        {
private String lastName;
private String firstName;
private String address;
private int clientID;
private int numVisits;
private double balance;
public int numberOfPets;
public Pet[] pet;

public Client()
{
    lastName = new String("unknown");
    firstName = new String("unknown");
    address = new String("unknown");
    clientID = 0;
    numVisits = 0;
    balance = 0;
    numberOfPets = 0;
    pet = null;
}
public Client(String inLast, String inFirst, String inAddress, String inID, String inVisits, String inBalance, String inPet )
{
    lastName = new String(inLast);
    firstName = new String(inFirst);
    address = new String(inAddress);
    clientID = Integer.parseInt(inID);
    numVisits = Integer.parseInt(inVisits);
    balance = Double.parseDouble(inBalance);
    numberOfPets = Integer.parseInt(inPet);
    Pet[] pet = new Pet[numberOfPets];
}
public String toString()
{
   return "\nClient Information: " + lastName + "," + firstName + "," + address + "," + clientID + "," + numVisits + "," + balance;

}
public boolean equals(Client other)
{
    return this.clientID == other.clientID;
}
 }
```

This is the Pet program

```
   public class Pet
   {
     private String name;
     private String animalType;
     private double weight;
     private String lastRabiesShot;
     private String lastVisit;

public Pet()
{
    name = new String("unknown");
    animalType = new String("unknown");
    weight = 0;
    lastRabiesShot = new String("unknown");
    lastVisit = new String("unknown");
}
public Pet(String inName, String inType, String inWeight, String inRabies, String inVisit)
{
    name = new String(inName);
    animalType = new String(inType);
    weight = Double.parseDouble(inWeight);
    lastRabiesShot = new String(inRabies);
    lastVisit = new String(inVisit);

}
public String toString()
{
    return "\nPet Information: " + name + "," + animalType + "," + weight + "," + lastRabiesShot + "," + lastVisit;
}
   }
```

This is the example text file (no spaces between lines).

Joe,Johnson,124 Heyo Avenue,15368,4,258.20,2

Arnold,Bulldog,58,4-2018-19,6-4-2020

Lucy,Retriever,14,4-11-2010,5-4-2010

Lewis,Lewis,145 Upchuck Road,78452,3.,185.51,1

Blake,Cat,12,01-6-09,02-09-2011

Miller, Millerson,136 Gunganns Everywhere Drive,96257,2,0.02,3

Major,Lab,102,07-12-2010,07-11-2013

Colonel,Collie,48,02-15-2018,03-15-2008

Captain,Lab,34,02-15-2018,03-15-2008

Rogers,Steve, 181 Ripoff Marvel Apt B,47895,1,25.08,1

Poppie,Cat,104,10-10-2009,10-10-2013

Master,Chief, 343 Unworthy Currently Lane,28257,4,343.00,4

Exuberant,Parrot,5,NA,3-13-2014

Guilty,German Shepard,88,11-25-2011,11-25-2015

Cortana,tabby cat,15,12-15-2012,05-15-2014

Roland,Collie,8,NA,2-5-2014

I apologize if the code formatting looks a little wonky.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok... point taken :-)  Anyway, reading the [tutorial about exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) still seems a good read (I'm deleting my previous comments now)

Answer (score 2):

You're shadowing the pet variable within Client:

```
class Client {
    // ....
    public Pet[] pet; // it's null here

    public Client() {
        // ...
        pet = null; // here it stays null
    }

    public Client(String inLast, String inFirst, String inAddress, String inID, String inVisits, String inBalance,
            String inPet) {
        // ...
        // here you **re-declare** the variable!!!! Don't do this. 
        Pet[] pet = new Pet[numberOfPets];  // the field remains null!!
    }
```

Don't do this, don't redeclare it, as this means that the field will always remain null.

Change

```
// you're setting a local variable here, not the pet field
Pet[] pet = new Pet[numberOfPets];
```

to

```
// Now you're setting the pet field
pet = new Pet[numberOfPets];
```

There are other issues with your code, including over-use of public fields allowing outside classes direct access to fields which they then manipulate. This risks increasing code complexity and side effects, a possible source for nasty bugs.

Comment: Thank You! This helped fix the error. I know about the public fields issue, if I can I will try to go back and fix that.

Comment: Now that I'm running the code I'm running into an error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at the line client[count] = new Client(data[0], data[1] etc. I know its because the [count] isn't reiterated as its staying at 0 the entire time. If I put this into a for loop (around just that line of code) the error transfers to the client[count].pet[0] line. If I put it inside the entirety of the while loop that it would consider any of the Pet objects I trying to create as a Client object and have problems at the Pet constructor. Do you have any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: @RecoveryZero: a new problem deserves a new question. But before you ask it, check the line that throws the error, check the value that's causing the exception to be thrown, search for similar questions on this, and first try to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
     m = 0;
       ///where to sort data
       while(m < 16)
       {
           String[] data = input[m].split(",");
           client[count] = new Client(data[0],data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6]);
           if(client[n].numberOfPets == 1)
           {
             m++;// **

look at here it starts to read 1, goes to loop check 15<16? yes it moves on m++ made m 16 and here it is you have 15 rows but it is looking for 16th row.

**
             String [] input2 = input[m].split(",");
             client[count].pet[0] = new Pet(input2[0], input2[1], input2[2], input2[3], input2[4]);

           }
```

Answer (score -3):

> client[count].pet[0] = new Pet(input2[0], input2[1], input2[2], input2[3], input2[4]); while inside the first for loop. Where is the NullPointerException coming from and how do I fix it?

Either `client` is null, or `client[count]` is null, or `client[count].pet` is null. Good luck.